# Draw a small part of large image in iOS fast

Tags: ios, image, draw

I would like to inspect a larger image by showing a small excerpt of it at the place where the finger is touching the screen. The drawing need to be very fast since if the finger moves the excerpt should follow.

I have tried `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect` with `CGContextDrawImage` but its noticeable slow and apparently can't be the best way since it creates new images.

Which other way to go if I want to draw a small portion of an image?

Comment: So effectively you want an image in the background with an opaque view in front of it but with a small section masked to transparent?

Comment: No, the background is a scaled down version of the large image (to fit screen) and in the foreground (or on top of it) is the excerpt in original size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an exact answer to your question but if I understand correctly you'd like something like a "magnifying glass" to inspect a portion of your image. Have you looked at something like: https://github.com/acoomans/iOS-MagnifyingGlass?